# How do I print on GUI instead of terminal?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have just started learning how to code, if anyone could help me it would be so appreciated!

All I am trying to do is to print my results on the GUI, I'm aware that printing goes straight to the terminal but I'm not sure how to figure this one out...

```
    from tkinter import *

window = Tk() #instantiate an instance of a window
window.geometry("360x360")
window.title("Gold River 2.0")

window.config(background="#181818")


#enter weekly earnings
earnings = Entry()
earnings.pack()

#calculate button

def calculate():
    total = earnings.get()
    print("$",total,"earnt")

    free = int(total) * 0.25
    print("FREE =",free)

    savings = int(total) * 0.30
    print("SAVINGS =",savings)

    business = int(total) * 0.15
    print("BUSINESS =",business)

    investment = int(total) * 0.20
    print("INVESTMENTS =",investment)

    gifts = int(total) * 0.10
    print("GIFTS =",gifts)

calculate = Button(window, text="Calculate", command=calculate)
calculate.pack()


window.mainloop() #places window on computer screen
```

Comment: You should use Labels in a Layout. I've never used tkinter but I think this link should help you: https://zetcode.com/tkinter/layout/ and particularly the section "Review example"

Comment: @penehama>In line 17. Change this total = earnings.get() to total = float(earnings.get())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Python's built in `print()` function to display the output on the Tkinter window, it is meant to be used to print a given message to the screen or to display an object’s value on the terminal.

So, instead of using print() you can Tkinter `Label` widgets, which are used to display a text or image on the screen.

Your Code can be modified like below:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk() #instantiate an instance of a window
window.geometry("360x360")
window.title("Gold River 2.0")

window.config(background="#181818")


#enter weekly earnings
earnings = Entry()
earnings.pack()

# Calculate button's function
def calculate():

    total = float(earnings.get())

    # label which shows value of 'total'
    total_label = Label(window, text=f"${total}  earnt")
    total_label.pack()

    free = int(total) * 0.25

    # label which shows value of 'free'
    free_label = Label(window, text=f"FREE = {free}")
    free_label.pack()

    savings = int(total) * 0.30

    # label which shows value of 'savings'
    savings_label = Label(window, text=f"SAVINGS = {savings} earnt")
    savings_label.pack()

    business = int(total) * 0.15

    # label which shows value of 'business'
    business_label = Label(window, text=f"BUSINESS = {business}")
    business_label.pack()

    investment = int(total) * 0.20

    # label which shows value of 'investment'
    investment_label = Label(window, text=f"INVESTMENTS = {investment}")
    investment_label.pack()

    gifts = int(total) * 0.10

    # label which shows value of 'gifts'
    gifts_label = Label(window, text=f"GIFTS = {gifts}")
    gifts_label.pack()


calculate = Button(window, text="Calculate", command=calculate)
calculate.pack()


window.mainloop() #places window on computer screen
```

To know more about `Tkinter Label` widgets -> [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-label/)

Comment: In line 17. Change this  total = earnings.get() to total = float(earnings.get())

Comment: Better used f-string format. total_label = Label(window, text=f"$ {total} earnt")